# How to save a picture using selenium without requests?

Tags: python, selenium, cloudflare

I have been testing  a website that uses CloudFlare DDoS protection so using requests to save a picture the standard way is not an option. 
Is there a way to save the picture directly with selenium ?

Comment: (I'm not too familiar with cloudflare, but) maybe whitelisting is an option?

Comment: You may try the java script executor then to download the image.